# CSharp async server program immediately closes at start

Tags: c#, asynchronous, server, udp

im pretty to new to programming and i've just now wrote my first async server, but as soon as i start the program, it closes right after writing waiting for new client, can someone help me out? I dont know what stupid thing im doing.
I have a class UDPServer with some methods, of which 
 - UDPServer() receives an ipendpoint of the localserver ipaddress and port to initialize stuff (called in main to create a new UDP server object)
 - right after that i call the get connection method, which supposedly should make the server wait for a new client, but instead it immediately closes.

```
// State object for reading client data asynchronously  
public class StateObject
{
    // Client  socket.  
    public Socket clientSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.  
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    // Receive buffer.  
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.  
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}


class UDPServer
{
    Socket serverSocket;
    IPEndPoint localIPEP;
    IPEndPoint senderIPEP;
    EndPoint sender;

    IPEndPoint[,] playerList; 
    int playerListIndex;

    bool waitingForSecondClient;

    public UDPServer(IPEndPoint serverIpEndPoint)
    {
        localIPEP = serverIpEndPoint;
        serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Dgram,ProtocolType.Udp);

        serverSocket.Bind(localIPEP);

        senderIPEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        sender = senderIPEP;

        playerList = new IPEndPoint[5000, 2]; // 5000 possible player lobbies, each with 2 player ip addresses and ports
        playerListIndex = 0; // we start filling up the lobbies from 0
        Console.WriteLine("Server setup complete.");
    }

    public void GetConnection()
    {
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for new client.");
        serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None,ref sender, ClientConnected, state);
    }

    public void ClientConnected(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        StateObject state = (StateObject)asyncResult;
        EndPoint remote = state.clientSocket.LocalEndPoint;
        StateObject tempState = new StateObject();
        int bytesReceived = serverSocket.EndReceiveFrom(asyncResult, ref remote);
        serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(tempState.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, ref remote, ClientConnected, tempState);


        Console.WriteLine("-------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Received bytes of data: " + bytesReceived);
        Console.WriteLine("-------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Received string: " + state.sb.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("-------------");

        if (state.sb.ToString().Equals("New client"))
        {
            Send(state.clientSocket, "Hello");
        }
    }

    private void Send(Socket client,string message)
    {
        EndPoint remote = client.LocalEndPoint;

        StateObject state = new StateObject();

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
        serverSocket.BeginSendTo(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,remote,SendCallback,state);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
        Socket client = (Socket)asyncResult.AsyncState;

        // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
        int bytesSent = client.EndSendTo(asyncResult);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UDPServer server = new UDPServer(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050));
        server.GetConnection();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[BeginReceiveFrom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.beginreceivefrom?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_BeginReceiveFrom_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Net_Sockets_SocketFlags_System_Net_EndPoint__System_AsyncCallback_System_Object_) Does not block, as such program execution reaches the end of your main method and finishes.  I am not sure what you intend your exit condition to be, but you will need some sort of code making sure the server waits until that exit condition is met before finishing program execution.

Comment: but i have seen many examples and they don't have anythin locking the code, i dont intend to have any exit conditions, as it is supposed to be a server for a game, but im currently trying async and trying to send messages from a client to servera and vice-versa, how could i halt the code as if i were using a sync socket?

Comment: Well, I would first say that you should always have an exit condition, all software eventually needs to restart.  And force killing programs is not the right way to do it.   That being said, you could wait on some sort of Wait Handle ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle ) and signal that when you want to exit